# SSH to device via USB

Tags: terminal, network, usb, ssh

When I try to SSH over USB to my device running linux, I get "ssh: connect to host 10.90.1.2 port 22: Network is unreachable"

Mind you, I can run the same command "ssh root@10.90.1.2" on my linux machine and another mac, but on my boss's brand new machine OSX, no dice.

If I type "ifconfig" on the working mac, I get an entry like

```
en2: flags=...
  ether 5a:...
  inet 10.90.1.1
```

On the non working machine, running if config shows a similar block except the part where I have "inet 10.90.1.1..." is missing.

On both machines I have gone to Network and set my RNDIS/Etho Gadget to configure IPv4 manually and have an IP address of 10.90.1.1.

Can anybody point me to a setting that might cause the ifconfig outputs to be different? I'm just not proficient with Macs.

Thanks.